# pandas calculation grouping by ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Is it possible to apply a calculation to a DF by ID.
For example if multiple records share a similar ID make that calculation but do it throughout the DF?

```py
df['Total Volume'] = df.groupby('ID')[df['VOLUME'].shift(-1) + df['ADDED'] - df['VOLUME']]
```

So I want to create the column "Total Volume" using the calculation

```py
df['VOLUME'].shift(-1) + df['ADDED'] - df['VOLUME']
```

I've had some success with this logic:

```py
df['Total Volume'] = df['VOLUME'].shift(-1) + df['ADDED'] - df['VOLUME']
```

But it doesn't take into account for the ID and the first record is always a total from another ID.

Ultimately the column should be blank or empty for the first record with every new ID.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your data?

Comment: where did `df1` come from?

Comment: I changed it, should have been df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to restrict the calculations to each "ID", right? Then you could use `groupby` + `shift` on "VOLUME" and do everything else the same.

```py
df['TOTAL VOLUME'] = df.groupby('ID')['VOLUME'].shift(-1) + df['ADDED'] - df['VOLUME']
```

Note that `shift(-1)` moves the next record up, so the end result is the last record in each "ID" is empty. Since you say:

> Ultimately the column should be blank or empty for the first record
> with every new ID

I think you want `shift(1)` instead (by default it's 1):

```py
df['TOTAL VOLUME'] = df.groupby('ID')['VOLUME'].shift() + df['ADDED'] - df['VOLUME']
```

Then again, the above code can be written even simpler using `groupby` + `diff`:

```py
df['TOTAL VOLUME'] = df['ADDED'] - df.groupby('ID')['VOLUME'].diff()
```